# Multiple category id with parent id gii ini product yii2

Tags: php, yii2, gii

I want to make a multiple category dropdown in product form yii2. The table category has a parent_id column. So when I want to choose the category with parent_id 0 or 1 it shows other categories with that parent_id. I use gii generator. Can you help me make controller model view it?
controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Product();
    $category = new Category();
    $time = time();
    $model->created_at = $time;
    $model->updated_at = $time;
    $dataCat = $category->getCategoryParent();
    if(empty($dataCat)){
        $dataCat = array();
    }
```

view

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList($dataCat,['prompt'=>'--obat--']) ?>
```

model

```
public function getCategoryParent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['idCate' => 'category_id']);
}
```

Comment: You need to provide what have you tried so far, otherwise, we can't help you much.

Comment: I think what you need the depdrop menu, try this http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `parent_id` in your category structure, I advice you to use nested-sets model, as you will face some technical limitations (like recursive query in SQL) and performance issues in the future.

There is a [good tree-manager extension developed by Krajee](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-tree-manager), that allows you to embed a good looking drop-down (support multiple) for category selection.
It has a good tree constructor in it as well.

[image: tree-view input]

Of course, you can implement such a functionality by yourself, but it's not that easy as it seems in the beginning.